# How to make Show/Hide in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

need help, I have a problem. I want to make it so that when one arrow(Top) disappears, another appears(down).

here is my code

```
return (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <FaChevronDown className='flachDown' onClick={(e) => {
      handleScrollDown();
      handleShow();
      if (!handleScrollUp) {
        { e.target.style.display = 'block' }
      } else {
        { e.target.style.display = 'none' }
      }
    }} />
    {isShown && (
      <FaChevronUp className='flachUp' onClick={(a) => {
        handleScrollUp();
        handleShow();
        if (!handleScrollDown) {
          { a.target.style.display = 'none' }
        } else {
          { a.target.style.display = 'block' }
        }
        
      }} />
    )}
    <Body />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Don't set style directly in a callback like you're doing. Use react state instead

Answer (score -2):

create a state variable:

```
import React ,{useState} from "react";
[visible,setVisible]=useState(false);
```

change it depending on the event that you want